# Engraved Design Lines on Mesh (Sword)

Tags: modeling, mesh

so I'm currently modelling the buster sword (crisis core version), and I've come across a problem with the engraved lines on the blade of the sword.

This is what I've done but I think there is a better way to do it because the method I'm doing is very messy and hard to fix (after subsurf modifier).

[image]

[image]

This is what happens with the bump map
[image: bump map]

Comment: Sculpt them -> bake them.

Answer (score 2):

Since the engravings are just very fine and only on a straight plane, I would suggest to use a normal map which simulates the engravings. So you can keep your mesh simple, while the engravings are always visible, depending on the light.